# Convert JSON table to JSON tree

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tree

I have the results of an SQL query in JSON format

```python
value = [
    {"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev a", "Identifier": "HMI 1"},
    {"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev a", "Identifier": "HMI 2"},
    {"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev b", "Identifier": "HMI 3"},
    {"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev c", "Identifier": "HMI 5"},
    {"Machine": "Mach 2", "Device": "Dev c", "Identifier": "HMI 6"},
    {"Machine": "Mach 2", "Device": "Dev d", "Identifier": "HMI 7"},
    {"Machine": "Mach 3", "Device": "Dev e", "Identifier": "HMI 8"}
]
```

I'm trying to generate a tree of the form:

```
Tree to be generated
[ ]- Mach 1
 +[ ]- Dev a
 |  +-- HMI 2
 |  +-- HMI 3
 +[ ]- Dev c
    +-- HMI 5
[ ]- Mach 2
 +[ ]- Dev c
 |  +-- HMI 6
 +[ ]- Dev d
 |  +-- HMI 7
 +[ ]- Dev e
    +-- HMI 8
```

The output of the function is to be used by [Inductive Automation's Perspective Tree component](https://docs.inductiveautomation.com/display/DOC81/Perspective+-+Tree) which expects it in the format:

```python
items = [
  {
    "label": "Mach 1",
    "expanded": true,
    "data": "",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Dev a",
        "expanded": true,
        "data": "",
        "items": [
          {
            "label": "HMI 1",
            "expanded": true,
            "data": {
              "Identifier": "HMI1",
              "Device": "Dev a",
              "Machine": "Mach 1"
            },
            "items": []
          },
          {
            "label": "HMI 2",
            "expanded": true,
            "data": {
              "Identifier": "HMI2",
              "Device": "Dev a",
              "Machine": "Mach 1"
            },
            "items": []
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Dev b",
        "expanded": true,
        "data": "",
        "items": [
          {
            "label": "HMI 3",
            "expanded": true,
            "data": {
              "Identifier": "HMI3",
              "Device": "Dev b",
              "Machine": "Mach 1"
            },
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  },

…
```

I have created some linear Python code for a tree depth of three but I'd like to modify it to work automatically with tree depth from 1 to 6 (or so) returned by the SQL query. (The sample input and output above is three-level.) Unfortunately I can't figure out how to modify this to work with recursion for a variable number of columns.

[image]

*Figure 1. The results of my lazy code (available on request).*

Can anyone suggest an approach using **Python** - the script language of the *Ignition* application I'm using?

Many thanks.

Comment: You speak about 6 levels. How does that work with the given data?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. The sample data hs three levels. I have coded manually for that but it doesn't scale well if I want to be able to make a more flexible tree-generating script. (I'm trying to make a general-purpose script that will generate a tree for various web-based dashboards. The number of tree levels will vary by application.) I thought that this would be a problem that had been solved many times but many hours of web searching has failed to find anything suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provide the order in which the keys should be used to drill down in the hierarchy. This is good practice, as the order of the keys in a dictionary might not represent the desired order.

Once you have these keys as a list, you could use it to iteratively dig deeper into the hierarchy.

```
def makeForest(values, levels):
    items = []  # The top level result array
    paths = {}  # Objects keyed by path
    root = { "items": items }  # Dummy: super root of the forest
    for data in values:
        parent = root
        path = ""
        for key in levels:
            label = data[key]
            path += repr([label])
            node = paths.get(path, None)
            if not node:
                node = {
                    "label": data[key],
                    "expanded": True,
                    "data": "",
                    "items": []
                }
                paths[path] = node
                parent["items"].append(node)
            parent = node
        parent["data"] = data
    return items

# Example use:
value = [{"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev a", "Identifier": "HMI 1"},{"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev a", "Identifier": "HMI 2"},{"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev b", "Identifier": "HMI 3"},{"Machine": "Mach 1", "Device": "Dev c", "Identifier": "HMI 5"},{"Machine": "Mach 2", "Device": "Dev c", "Identifier": "HMI 6"},{"Machine": "Mach 2", "Device": "Dev d", "Identifier": "HMI 7"},{"Machine": "Mach 3", "Device": "Dev e", "Identifier": "HMI 8"}]
forest = makeForest(value, ["Machine", "Device", "Identifier"])
print(forest)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that and the output appears to be exactly what I want but I'm afraid you missed the `python` tag! I'll edit to make it clearer. I'll also see if I can figure out how to Pythonize your answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, I will do the conversion to Python. Hold on.

Comment: Updated to python.

Comment: What a guy! It's great to be multi-lingual. I'm an automation engineer and work with a wide variety of systems so I never get to be really good at any of them. This seems to work as required. I'll check it out, try to understand it, and report back. Thank you again.